# How can I speed up saving/processing of pdfs?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I work in printing and I frequently get large pdfs (2000 pages) and saving them and imposing them takes FOREVER even if I chunk it into say 10 files of 200 pages.

The main culprits seems to be consolidating duplicate fonts and saving for fast web viewing. I've disabled the latter in the settings but I don't know how else to try and speed up processing and saving pdfs with a large number of pages.

Optimizing isn't really a solid option since most of the files I work with I can't risk image degradation.

Any tips for me?

UPDATED:

[System Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G62Br.png)

Comment: Buy a more powerful PC ;)

Comment: Not really my call since it would be up to the company I work for. I would if I could but trying to make the best of a bad situation :p

Comment: What utility are you using to impose? or… how do you impose?

Comment: 2 ways: I use Quite Imposing plugin for Acrobat and I use an imposition script called Rhimposition for InDesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of physically updating the hardware, your options are quite limited.

1) If your work pc has an E-SATA port there is a chance you could gain some read/write advantage by using an external SSD/flash storage. Given my knowledge of most work-provisioned computers, it is unlikely you'll find an ESATA port.

2) If you can offload this work to a more powerful computer, that'd sure help.

PDFs are handy but often cumbersome. You will be ultimately limited by the read/write and processing speed/channels of your PC, which it would appear you have little power over. I'd say the best course of action would be to petition your IT department for an upgrade citing the sluggish performance for these tasks.

Comment: Updated original post with specs.